# How to produce a modal bottom to top animation with react-native-paper Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-paper

I want to create a modal sliding view that appears from the bottom of my screen in react-native, using [react-native-paper `<Modal />` component](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/modal.html).

I use `<Animated />` from react-native for the animation and my target are: web, android, and iOS.

This is what I have tried:

https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/react-native-paper-modal-bottom-to-top-animation

- web: the animation seems to be truncated
- ios: no animation at all
- android: I have an error: `Uncaught Error: Error while updating property 'transform' of a view managed by: RCTView`

How can I build a slide bottom to top panel animation using the react-native paper modal?

> I found the original [modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal.html#animationtype) from `react-native` to be exactly what I want, except it does not have a clickable backdrop to close the overlay that has react-native-paper, see react-native original modal demo [here](https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-9nMRCakcg&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=razcrv10d5&supportedPlatforms=android,ios&name=Modal&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

I'm using this lib to create modal bottom dialog for my app, and so far so good ;)

Please take a look ;)

Comment: It work well on ios and android. I haven't tried it on web.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a way you can use it**

```
import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper';
    
 <Modal visible={visible} onDismiss={this._hideModal}>
    
 </Modal>
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@kopax/react-native-paper-modal-bottom-to-top-animation